# Блок autocomplete в chrome не правильно позиционируется

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile-web

На мобильных устройствах при автозаполнении блок предлагающий один из аккаунтов распологается не под инпутом. Форма автозаполнения позиционируется абсолютно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сложно без примера кода подсказать вам решение. Однако можно убрать форму автозаполнения полностью:

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```